# error expected unqualified-id before '[' token (with array)

Tags: c++

[my code]

I get this error when I try to declare an array(line 10).Any help would be nice.
i don't know what is wrong, I think my syntax is right.After that i try to move data from a file to the array and compare the elements in the array.

http://prntscr.com/5maksi

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int k = 0;
    int n;
    int [y];

    cout << "write n";
    cin >> n;

    FILE*EIS;                       

    EIS = fopen("xxx.in.text","r");

    EIS >> [y];

    for(x=0;x<n , x++ )
        if ([x] > [x + 1] ) {
            k = k++;
        }

    FILE*EKS;

    EKS = fopen("xxx.out.text","w")
    k >> EKS;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the code in the question and not in a link

Comment: [My answer....]

Comment: What is with `int [y]` that is *on the line reported in the error message*?

Comment: Look up the proper use of `FILE*` (or `ifstream`, which is probably what you wanted anyway) and how to declare and index an array.

Comment: indeed namfuak, i used ifstream and it is better with no errors,thanks

Answer (score 1):

`int [y]` is a completely incorrect method of declaring an array. This is how you do it.

`int y[5]` is acceptable however. 5 can be any `const` variable.

You may want to use if stream as Namfuak suggested.

Comment: If it worked then hit the accept button ;) if you can.